# How do you re-write the rm() function in R to clear your workspace automatically

Tags: r

I've extracted the function for `rm()` in R (because I'm annoyed at having to type `rm(list=ls())` everytime I want to clear my environment; it get's dirty fast) and I've tried modifying it to automatically use the `list=ls()` code but it hasn't worked. Can anyone else figure out a way to edit this function to automatically do what `rm(list=ls())` does but not delete itself.

```
function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), 
    inherits = FALSE) 
{
    dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
    if (length(dots) && !all(sapply(dots, function(x) is.symbol(x) || 
        is.character(x)))) 
        stop("... must contain names or character strings")
    names <- sapply(dots, as.character)
    if (length(names) == 0L) 
        names <- character()
    list <- .Primitive("c")(list, names)
    .Internal(remove(list, envir, inherits))
}
```

FYI:
`clr <- rm(list=ls())` doesn't work either.

Comment: `f <- function() with(.GlobalEnv, rm(list=ls()))`  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Pascal I think it isn't a duplicate because I'm creating a new function rather than using rm(); although that solution does seem to have a similar result. Really all that needs to be done to keep it from being deleted, apparently, is to add a "." before the function name, let's call it ".clr" then. My question remains the same. How do you edit the function above.

Comment: Unless you know how to use `.Internal()` that's going to be pretty hard

Comment: Something like `myrm<-function() rm(list=setdiff(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv),"myrm"),envir=.GlobalEnv)` should work

Comment: @timothy.s.lau You are more asking others to create it for you.

Comment: The answer is: ``function(){vector1 <- setdiff(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), lsf.str(envir = .GlobalEnv)[]); rm(list = vector1, pos = 1)}``